# Slow rendering of 25 MB raster in ArcScene

Tags: arcgis-desktop, performance, 3d-analyst, arcscene, virtual-machine

I am loading one raster layer that is 25 MB in size. It is a 1926x2042 1m DEM. I need to render it at a cell size of one for optimal display of the layer. When I open a saved .mxd with the only the raster, it takes ~ 10 minutes. Every time I go into the layer properties and hit OK, it takes about 5 minutes to load, even if I don't change any settings. If I change the color ramp it takes even longer.

I'm running Arc from a 2 TB hard drive on Parallels. The virtual machine has 2 GB of RAM designated, and 2GB of virtual memory. I allocated 4 GB of virtual memory according to ESRI's help page (http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/3d-analyst/optimizing-arcscene.htm), but still have the same problem. I've come across people with issues with 100-200MB files, but not with a 25 MB file.

When the layer does load, I can move around fine and this is great. However I have more similar sized rasters to load into ArcScene, and am in a crunch for time.

If this is a normal amount of time for a file of this size, does anyone know if it is possible to speed up rendering times?

Comment: For 25MB 5-10min seems to be an excessive amount of time needed. Have you built a pyramid layer for the raster?

Comment: I'd assumed that it had already been built. I began with an ASCII file and imported into ArcMap to define its coordinate system and project it, and am pretty sure I was asked to build pyramids for it at some point during that process. How can I check?